# Outlook 2010 Message Rules for Sending Text Alert

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

I use Outlook 2010 rules a lot, but am stumped on this one.  When a message meeting certain criteria arrive, such as "Importance: High", how do I send out an email to another address?

It is easy to forward the whole message, but what I really want to do is send email to my cell phone 510xxxxxxx@vtext.com, with the subject only template "Important Message in your Inbox"

I want this to be a server side rule, since it will then run without my account being logged in.

Any Ideas?

Noah Hart